# Сериализация Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Есть endpoint для создания пользователя
`/api/v1/accounts/create/`

При успешной регистрации возвращается такой json:

```
{
    "id": 34,
    "first_name": "Илья",
    "email": "daniil2d0a0n0iisl@gmail.com"
}
```

Хотелось бы немного изменить структуру json:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "result": {
        "account": {
            "id": 34,
            "first_name": "Илья",
            "email": "daniil2d0a0n0iisl@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

**serializers.py**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class AccountCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False,
                                             write_only=True,
                                             max_length=128,
                                             label='Повторите пароль')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'email', 'password', 'confirm_password')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'first_name': {
                'required': True,
                'allow_blank': False
            },
            'password': {
                'write_only': True
            },
            'email': {
                'required': True,
                'allow_blank': False
            }
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        user = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

**views.py**

```py
from . import serializers
from rest_framework import generics


class AccountCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    serializer_class = serializers.AccountCreateSerializer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы изменить ваш json на новый, можно переопределить метод create, например:

```
from rest_framework import status


class AccountCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
"""
Здесь ваш код
"""
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        new_serializer_data = {
            "status": "ok",
            "result": {
                "account": serializer.data
            }
        }
        return Response(new_serializer_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого в стандартном сериализаторе предусмотрен метод `to_representation`:

```
class AccountCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return {
            'score': obj.score,
            'player_name': obj.player_name
        }
    ...
```